# Is there any way to retry different in method when a particular method failing (instead of retrying that failed method)

Tags: resttemplate, spring-retry, retry-logic

I have a requirement in which I have 2 methods (in different class) , in which one method makes Rest GET call to fetch token(which is like session token and valid for few seconds) and another method which append this retrieved token in headers and make a Rest POST call, so whenever POST call fails because of token expiration I need to retry GET call  method(instead of retrying POST call alone) to fetch new token and use token in POST request headers and retry post call(with new token). I could see retryable retries only failed method, in my case it retries POST call alone so it endup in retrying post call method with expired token. I want to retry Get method and POST method when post method failed for expired token. So I want to know is there any way to retry different method when particular method fails. Appreciate your help.

Retryable class(getCSRFToken- get call, sapPost-post call)

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Backoff;
import org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RestTemplateRetry extends AbstractRestTemplate{

    @Retryable(value= {Exception.class}, maxAttempts=5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
    public ResponseEntity<String> getCSRFToken (HttpEntity<String> entity, String getUrl) throws Exception{
        ResponseEntity<String> csrfToken= getRestTempalte().exchange(getUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        return csrfToken;
    }

    @Retryable(value= {Exception.class}, maxAttempts=5, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
    public ResponseEntity<String> sapPost (HttpEntity<String> entity, String postUrl)throws  Exception{
        ResponseEntity<String> response= getRestTempalte().exchange(postUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Listener class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryCallback;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;
import org.springframework.retry.listener.RetryListenerSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RetryListener extends RetryListenerSupport {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(
            RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        log.warn("Retryable method {} threw {}th, attempted retries = {} with exception {}",
                context.getAttribute("context.name"),
                context.getRetryCount(), context.getRetryCount() - 1, throwable.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No; that is not supported; you need to write custom code for these more complex scenarios.